# How to 'drush sql-dump' all databases

Tags: 7, database, drush

I have two databases I connect to with drupal. Does `drush sql-dump` back up all databases defined in settings.php?

If not how can I create dumps of both databases?

I've attempted using the `--database=db_to_backup` option but it throws an error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "&&" unexpected
Database dump failed
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your database connection on settings.php looks like

```
$databases = array(
  'default' =>
  array(
    'default' =>
    array(
      'database' => 'mydatabase1',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'test' =>
  array(
    'default' =>
    array(
      'database' => 'mydatabase2',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

The following command will back up both the data bases;

```
drush sql-dump --database=default --result-file=default.sql; drush sql-dump --database=test --result-file=test.sql
```

Comment: thanks - I was using the sql name instead of the key defined in settings.php